# How to make something outside a loop happen when the inside is true

Tags: python

```
def add_pairing():
    found = False
    letter=input("What letter would you like to add?")
    symbol=input("\nWhat symbol would you like to pair with")
    for clue in clues:
        if letter in clue:
            print("You have entered an invalid letter ")
        elif symbol in clue:
            print("You have entered an invalid symbol")
```

**#The code below needs to occur when letter and symbol are not in 'clue'**

```
   else:
        print("The pairing has been added")
        clues.append(letter + symbol)
        print (clues)
        return clues
```

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of indenting properly? Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: That code looks fine to me assuming correct indentation. The `for`... `else` syntax is perfectly valid.

Comment: Please ask a new question...

Comment: OK, I'll ask a new question...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that if *any* `clue` contains either a `letter` or a `symbol` you want to not add the pairing, you can do:

```
def add_pairing():
    found = False
    letter=input("What letter would you like to add?")
    symbol=input("\nWhat symbol would you like to pair with")
    for clue in clues:
        if letter in clue:
            print("You have entered an invalid letter ")
            break
        elif symbol in clue:
            print("You have entered an invalid symbol")
            break
    else:
        print("The pairing has been added")
        clues.append(letter + symbol)
        print (clues)
        return clues
```

Note that I have added `break` in your `if` and `elif`, which will immediately end the `for` loop, skip the `else` block and end the function. The `else` on a `for` only runs if the loop finishes without `break`. This function will either `return clues` with the new pairing added or `return None`.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for your help! However I think it might be easier if I do a dictionary instead of a list especially in the upcoming tasks I have to do..

Answer (score 2):

To have a similar code that is easier to read

```
def add_pairing():
    found = False
    letter = input("What letter would you like to add?")
    symbol = input("\nWhat symbol would you like to pair with")

    if any(letter in clue for clue in clues):
        print("You have entered an invalid letter")
    elif any(symbol in clue for clue in clues):
        print("You have entered an invalid symbol")
    else:
        print("The pairing has been added")
        clues.append(letter + symbol)
        print (clues)
        return clues
```

But could it be easier to have a dictionary instead of a list:

```
clues = {}
def add_pairing():
    letter = input("What letter would you like to add?")
    symbol = input("\nWhat symbol would you like to pair with")

    if letter in clues:
        print("You have entered an invalid letter")
    elif symbol in clues.values():
        print("You have entered an invalid symbol")
    else:
        print("The pairing has been added")
        clues[letter] = symbol
        print (clues)
        return clues
```

Comment: Hi there Antti, thanks for the quick reply... I think it would be better changing it to a dictionary however to do this I will need to change some of the code in one of the earlier tasks... I have added this in on the question... If you could help that would be great! Thanks

Comment: You don't need the `.keys()`; python iterates over the keys of a dictionary by default

Comment: @jonrsharpe indeed, was a bit tired

Comment: So how do I change the bit of code I added to a dictionary?

Comment: @user3633316 I have rolled back that edit; you should make an effort to figure it out yourself. Start by reading [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: @user3633316 jon wants you to read  [this really (python 3)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: basically dictionary is a datastructure that maps *keys* to *values*, in this case letters are keys, and symbols are values

Comment: I know what a dictionary does it is just I am struggling to add it into my code. I don't want to edit the code I already have and mess it up... Should I post all my code for you to look at?

Comment: I have added the parts of my code that need to be changed into the question for you to look at... I have labelled the necessary bits that need editing. Thanks